# Свойства классов в JS

Tags: extjs

Здравствуйте. Имеется рабочий стол на ExtJS. Мне надо допилить его. Понял, что там все объектно-ориентированно, хоть и криво как-то.
Проблема: в класс Ext.app добавляю свойство     taskBar: null. 
Далее в описании метода приложения Init инициализирую эту переменную
    this.taskBar = Ext.select('div#ux-taskbar');
Через пару строчек обращаюсь спрятать: this.taskBar.hide();  - все норм.
Еще через пару строк (после авторизации) хочу показать обратно this.taskBar.show();
На show() получаю  "this.taskBar is undefined"
Все это происходит в одном методе этого класса. Почему? Пару строк назад смог обратиться и спрятать, а показать не могу?

Выкладываю весь класс:

```
Ext.extend(Ext.app.App, Ext.util.Observable, {

isReady: false,
startMenu: null,
userMenu: null,
modules: null,
module: null,
isGuest: true,
login_window: null,
userInfo: null,
taskBar: null, // объявление

initApp : function(){

    //инициализация
    this.taskBar = Ext.select('div#ux-taskbar');

    if(this.modules){
        this.initModules(this.modules);
    }
    this.launcher = this.desktop.taskbar.userMenu;
    this.module = this.getLogout();
    if(this.module){
        this.initModules(this.module);
    }
    this.init();

//        var user_taskbar = Ext.select('div#ux-taskbar');
//        user_taskbar.hide();
    //прячем - норм работает
    this.taskBar.hide();
    var domElement = Ext.get("all-elements");
    var maskLogin = new Ext.LoadMask(domElement, {msg:"Проверка аутентификации. Ожидание ответа сервера..."});
    maskLogin.show();

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'index.php?r=Ajax/isGuest',
        disableCaching:false,
        success: function(response, options){
            maskLogin.hide();
            console.log('Запрос выполнен.');
            switch(response.responseText)
            {
                case '1': 
                    StartLoginWindow();
                    break;
                case '0': 
                    Ext.app.isGuest = false;
                    this.taskBar.show(); // здесь! taskBar is undefined
                    GetUserInfo();
                    break;                
                default: Ext.MessageBox.show({title:'Ошибка аутентификации',msg: 'Неизвестная ошибка',buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK}); return;
            }
        },
        failure: function(response, options){
            maskLogin.hide();
            Ext.MessageBox.show({title:'Ошибка',msg: 'Не удалось выполнить запрос',buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK}); return;                
        }
    });

},
...
});
```

П.С. Как бы пытаюсь действовать в соответствии с принципами этого фреймворка и логикой: "не обращаться повсюду через DOM, а лишь при инициализации, а далее через объект".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внутри `Ext.Ajax.request({`
`this` будет уже другой объект. Чтобы достучатся до вашего объекта либо scope надо использовать либо

```
this.taskBar.hide();
var domElement = Ext.get("all-elements");
var maskLogin = new Ext.LoadMask(domElement, {msg:"Проверка аутентификации. Ожидание ответа сервера..."});
maskLogin.show();

var myObj = this; //в переменной ссылка на класс

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'index.php?r=Ajax/isGuest',
    disableCaching:false,
    success: function(response, options){
        maskLogin.hide();
        console.log('Запрос выполнен.');
        switch(response.responseText)
        {
            case '1': 
                StartLoginWindow();
                break;
            case '0': 
                Ext.app.isGuest = false;
                myObj.taskBar.show(); // тут уже все будет работать
                GetUserInfo();
                break;                
            default: Ext.MessageBox.show({title:'Ошибка аутентификации',msg: 'Неизвестная ошибка',buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK}); return;
        }
    },
```

Comment: @ilyas, спасибо. Тоже опытным путем к этому пришел уже, когда вынес за пределы запроса.